# How to create 2 timers in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

View Setup:
- Content View with a timer that triggers every second to update a label
- A modal with a timer that triggers every second to update a different label (in the modal)

Question: Why does the timer in the modal never work? Is this a limitation of SwiftUI? Is this a limitation of publishers? I am beyond confused why this will not work.

Please see the below code as an example

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingCounter = false

    @State var counter = 0

    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("count: \(counter)")
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    self.counter += 1
            }

            Button(action: {
                self.isShowingCounter.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Test View counter")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingCounter) { TestView() }
    }
}


struct TestView: View {
    @State var count = 0

    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(count)")
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                self.count += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. It seems like `TestView()` is called every sec from the `ContentView` as it is updated, thus completely resets the timer/ content of the modal view every sec too. If you remove the subscription from the `ContentView`, the timer in `TestView` will begin to work. Not sure how best to fix that/ maintain separate states for these two views.

Comment: @aunnnn quite perplexing indeed as you would expect the label in ContentView to update every second, however not the modal overtop...  This could be solved by a timer in a singleton but that really is terribly messy..... and the inefficiency would still occur...